# Why is the condition in this while loop: "curr != NULL"?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I am trying to understand the stack data structure in c++, and this `show()` function is confusing me. Can someone explain to me why the while loop's condition in the `show()` function is `curr != NULL`. I understand that in a linked list data structure, the last node in the list points to NULL, so therefore it makes sense for that to be the stopping condition when traversing a linked list, but I don't see here that the last node in a stack points to NULL, unless I am not seeing things clearly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct StackNode {
    int n;
    StackNode *previous;

};

class Stack {
    private:
        StackNode *top;

    public:
        Stack() {
            top = NULL;
        }
        ~Stack(){};

        void push(int value) {
            StackNode *new_node = new StackNode();
            new_node->n = value;
            new_node->previous = top;
            top = new_node;
        }

        void show() {
            StackNode *curr;
            curr = top;

            while (curr != NULL) {
                cout << curr->n << endl;
                curr = curr->previous;
            }
        }
};

int main() {

    Stack S;

    S.push(1);
    S.push(2);
    S.push(3);
    S.show();
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This code as shown doesn't compile at all: It's missing a definition of the `Stack` class. It seems likely that in the code you aren't showing, the `Stack` constructor initializes `top` to `NULL`, which will mean that `new_node->previous = top;` will assign `NULL` to `new_node->previous` the first time a value is pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @NathanPierson I fixed it, sorry about that

Comment: With the new information we can see that Nathan's conjecture is correct. The `NULL` will be inherited from the initial value of `top`.

Comment: Side note: `Stack() { top = NULL; }` could be `Stack(): top(NULL) {}` or `StackNode *top = NULL;` and `Stack(){}`. It doesn't matter here, because the default initialization of a pointer is to do nothing, but all members are initialized before entering the body of the constructor. If you have a member with expensive default construction or assignment logic, you can save a lot of effort by explicitly initializing the member in the member initializer list or with a default initializer rather than default constructing and then assigning to the correct value.

Comment: Additional note: Prefer [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) to `NULL` in modern C++. `nullptr` has a proper type rather than being an integer 0 cast to a pointer, and that type allows the compiler to perform  additional checking that can save your bacon.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom element of the `Stack` doesn't have a `previous` node, and it is `NULL` so that is the loop's stop condition.

When a stack starts, the `top` node is `NULL`, as you `push` elements to it, the firs you add will have `previous=NULL`, because of this code:

```cpp
        void push(int value) {
            StackNode *new_node = new StackNode();
            new_node->n = value;
            new_node->previous = top; //<1>
            top = new_node;
        }
```

<1>: `top` was pointing to `NULL` before adding the first (and bottom) element, from that moment the bottom element has `previous` set to `NULL`.

This code doesn't show the `pop` operation, but presumably, when the `Stack`
gets emptied `top` should be `NULL` again.